# How to classify segments with ticks in different positions?

Tags: algorithm

All segments have four ticks(ABCD). But their positions are different on different segments. For example, they have following partterns:

```
1, ______________A___B__C__D (ABCD at right end)
2, A______B_____C______D (ABCD is distributed evenly)
3, A__B___________________C__D (ABCD at two ends)
4, A_B__C__D_________________ (ABCD at left end)
5, A__________B_C____________D (ABCD at two ends and the middle of the segment)
```

Is there an algorithm that can distinguish these five patterns? More importantly, I don't know the patterns of those segments ahead, so the computer has to learn the patterns by itself.

Sorry for my English. I will appreciate your answers.

Comment: Can you provide more context to help us understand what and where you are having problems? A code sample of what you've tried? For example, do you need a regex to find A,B,etc. with underscores or is the actual data different?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a certain amount of opinion in how you specify the meaning of these categories.

Let's assume the segment length is always of length 13, for now, to make it easier to think about. If necessary we can relax that assumption later.

Even distribution implies equal, or as near to equal as possible, gaps between letters - in particular, if the segment length is 13, then this gap must be exactly 3.

In all other cases:

At the right end implies they're all after the midpoint (13 / 2, which is 6.5), and likewise, at the left end implies they're all before the midpoint.

At the two ends and the middle implies (to me, from your example) that the gap between B and C is smaller than the minimum of the gap between A and B and the gap between C and D.

Which just leaves ABCD at two ends, so if it's not any of those cases, it must be this case.